# SSRS Report Parameter Dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a report with three parameters (Year, Month & Market).
I can select Parameters values normally, but if I changed Year value it refresh all parameters so it should refresh Months but the Market shouldn't refresh , 
so the question is why Market refresh too ?! and how can I avoid refreshing it?
[Picture 1 when the client select all parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5ce7.png)

[Picture 2 when the client change his year selection from 2017 to 2016 it refresh all parameters except Market, Line & FLM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcENG.png)

Comment: Propably the market dataset query where clause is referencing the year and month parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameters order and set market as the first parameter.

For example, your current parameter order is:

[image]

Use the [image] icon to move the market at first.

it should look like:

[image]

In this way, changing year or month won't change the market.

Otherwise, you can also use **never refresh** option.

For this. go to parameter properties -> Advance -> Select never refresh.:

[image]

Comment: Changing the parameter order won't work if there is reference in the year or month parameter in the market dataset query

Comment: by changing the orders of parameter it works well , but the client needs the order Year , Month & Market ...

Comment: @niktrs I checked the market dataset parameters it depends on logged in user only nothing depends on the Year or Month

Comment: What if you load default value in year and month params? Is that still refreshing market?

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Are you getting year n month values from dataset or they are static?

Comment: And when u say market refresh, what does that mean? Can u share the market dataset details and value of market after and before refresh? We are still trying to hit our head in the wall without seeing example or values

Comment: @Viking thanks for your help, I edited the question and added two Screenshots